# How to implement Navigation to ViewControlller on RowSelect delegate method in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am working for navigation from Table View to View Controller, when I am clicking row I got exception as System.NullReferenceException has been thrown Object reference not set to an instance of an object in xamarin.ios

```
public override void Row Selected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

   // Error System.NullReferenceException

   _contact.NavigationController.PushViewController(new incomingscreen(),true);

}
```

Comment: is your TableViewController already contained in a UINavigationController?  If it is not, the NavigationController property will be null.

Comment: hi jason ,In the above code the rowselect method is not been called when running on the device